# How can I restrict input into a TextInputCell in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to restrict input into a GWT TextInputCell for things like monetary values, dates, SSNs, etc. I'd like to restrict the character that they can type in to the field using a regular expression (ideally). I'm guessing that the only way to do this is to override the onBrowserEvent method on the TextInputCell, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

What is the best way to mask my input cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onBrowserEvent` method receives a [NativeEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html), which has a `preventDefault` method. You probably want to call that `preventDefault` method whenever `getKeyCode` on the native event returns a character that you want to block.

See also the [KeyCodes](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyCodes.html) class, which can be handy for testing for special keys.

Comment: Excellent! I finally got something working with capturing keyup/keydown events and trimming, but the preventDefault works much better! I'll post my ultimate solution as a separate answer, but I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

So here is my solution (based on David's great feedback):

First, there is a limitation in the TextInputCell in that it can't handle native `keypress` events, so I had to create a near-exact copy of the class and add the `keypress` event type to the constructor where it passes in the event types that the cell can handle to the super constructor. Let's call this class `KeyPressableTextInputCell`. See this thread where I discussed this solution: [Why isn't the keypress event being sent to GWT's TextInputCell.onBrowserEvent() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738583/why-isnt-the-keypress-event-being-sent-to-gwts-textinputcell-onbrowserevent-m)

Then, I created a MaskedTextInputCell class that overrides the `onBrowserEvent()` method and prevents invalid keystrokes as they're typing, and also checks the overall form of the field. For example, valid monetary keystrokes are 0-9 and the decimal point. The overall form has to be numbers only, with only a single decimal point. Both of these checks are done using a strategy interface that I called `ValidationStrategy` and put directly in the MaskedTextInputCell.

```
public class MaskedTextInputCell extends KeyPressableTextInputCell {
    public interface ValidationStrategy {
        public boolean matches(String valueToCheck);
    }

    private ValidationStrategy overallFormValidationStrategy;
    private ValidationStrategy validKeystrokeValidationStrategy;

    public MaskedTextInputCell(ValidationStrategy overallFormValidationStrategy,
            ValidationStrategy validKeystrokeValidationStrategy) {
        this.overallFormValidationStrategy = overallFormValidationStrategy;
        this.validKeystrokeValidationStrategy = validKeystrokeValidationStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Element parent, String value, Object key, NativeEvent event,
            ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(parent, value, key, event, valueUpdater);

        if ("keypress".equals(event.getType())) {
            String keystroke = String.valueOf((char) event.getCharCode());
            handleInvalidKeystroke(keystroke, event);
        } else if ("blur".equals(event.getType()) || "keyup".equals(event.getType())) {
            String valueInInputElement = getInputElement(parent).getValue();
            handleInvalidOverallForm(valueInInputElement);
        }
    }
    protected void handleInvalidOverallForm(String valueOfEntireField) {
        if (!overallFormValidationStrategy.matches(valueOfEntireField)) {
            //You could fire an event here to turn the cell red...
            GWT.log("Invalid form.");
        }
    }
    protected void handleInvalidKeystroke(String keystroke, NativeEvent event) {
        if (!validKeystrokeValidationStrategy.matches(keystroke)) {
            GWT.log("Invalid keystroke.");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

I then created a regular expression implementation of the ValidationStrategy:

```
public class RegularExpressionValidationStrategy implements MaskedTextInputCell.ValidationStrategy {
    private String regularExpression;
    public RegularExpressionValidationStrategy(String regularExpression) {
        this.regularExpression = regularExpression;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean matches(String valueToCheck) {
        return valueToCheck.matches(regularExpression);
    }
}
```

Now, I can do something like this to create a money field:

```
public class MonetaryTextInputCell extends MaskedTextInputCell {
    public MonetaryTextInputCell() {
        super(new RegularExpressionValidationStrategy("[0-9.]"), 
              new RegularExpressionValidationStrategy("^[0-9.][0-9]*[0-9.]?[0-9]*$"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you check the combination key, like SHIFT+anykey>